# Javaee 5 Rest Exception - Alternatives

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, was

We have an application that uses the modern JAX-RS implementations to call a REST service. However, this was deployed to a WAS-7 which uses J2EE-5 under the hood. The code looks like this

```
Client client = new Client();

Builder request = client.target("http:\\abc.com").path("path\to\endpoint")
                 .property("propA", securityType)
                 .request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

This implementation works flawlessly in WAS8 (with J2EE6). Due to architectural concerns we can't migrate to a WAS8 just yet. When this code is run on WAS7, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder
           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:432)
           at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:201)
```

I've done a lot of research to find a good and simple example of a REST Client implementation in **J2EE-5**, but have had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not hard as you think.

if you compare J2EE5 and J2EE6.

|Java EE 5 (JSR-244)    |Java EE 6 (JSR-316)

|nothing for JAX-RS          |new! JAX-RS 1.1 JSR 311

you can refer to [here](http://alexander.holbreich.org/javaee5-vs-javaee6/) for more difference.

That is to say, you only add JAX-RS releated jar to your application. Then you will be fine.

Comment: Would it not cause a conflict with the existing j2ee 5 jars in any shape or form?

Comment: I don't think so. As J2EE 5 has no such jar for RS yet. Try it.